# Event doesn't get added in a for-loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

This is the html. If a link is clicked I want to replace the span-element in front of it with some text.

```
<p><span id="sp1">that1</span> <a href="#" id="update1">Update1</a></p>
<p><span id="sp2">that2</span> <a href="#" id="update2">Update2</a></p>
<p><span id="sp3">that3</span> <a href="#" id="update3">Update3</a></p>
<p><span id="sp4">that4</span> <a href="#" id="update4">Update4</a></p>
<p><span id="sp5">that5</span> <a href="#" id="update5">Update5</a></p>
```

As you can see, my idea was to give the spans en the anchors identical id's and a number.

In my jquery-code I loop through all the anchor-elements, give them a click-event that causes the span-element in front of it to be replaced.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

  $(document).ready(function() {
   var numSpans = $("span").length;
   for (n=0;n<=numSpans;n++) {
     $("a#update" + n).click(function(e){
       $('span#sp' + n).replaceWith('this');
       e.preventDefault();
     });    
   }   
  });

</script>
```

For some reason this does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @zod that's part of the solution but just a link like that is not so useful (unless you already know the answer).

Comment: @Matt It will surely useful for a new user. Dont worry

Comment: The problem here is a closure problem, not an event-binding problem

Comment: @Eric and yet the problem is solved by using a different event binding paradigm.

Comment: @Matt: Indeed. However, the question was "What am I doing wrong?", not "How should I write this code". What he's doing wrong is assuming that the variable `n` maintains its value when kept in a closure at the point of declaration.

Comment: @Eric Indeed that was the question. I will look into your answer you have given below. Can't say I understand it yet, but I will learn from it. Thanks.

Comment: @zod Thanks for the link. I am only just dabbling in jQuery and every new bit of info is very welcome!

Comment: @zod: Stack Overflow frowns upon links without explanations.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your original code is that you're creating a closure on the variable `n`. When the event handler is called, it is called with the value of `n` at the point of invocation, not the point of declaration. You can see this by adding an alert call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var numSpans = $("span").length;
    for (n = 1; n <= numSpans; n++) {
        $("a#update" + n).click(function(e) {
            alert(n); //Alerts '6'
            $('span#sp' + n).replaceWith('this');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
})
```

One way to fix this is to create a closure on the value of n in each iteration, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var numSpans = $("span").length;
    for (n = 1; n <= numSpans; n++) {
        $("a#update" + n).click(
            (function(k) {
                return function(e) {
                    alert(k);
                    $('span#sp' + k).replaceWith('this');
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            })(n)
        );
    }
})
```

However, this is messy, and you'd do better to use a more jQuery-y method.

---

One way to do this would be to remove the `id`s from your code. Unless you need them for something else, they're not required:

```
<p><span>that1</span> <a href="#" class="update">Update1</a></p>
<p><span>that2</span> <a href="#" class="update">Update2</a></p>
<p><span>that3</span> <a href="#" class="update">Update3</a></p>
<p><span>that4</span> <a href="#" class="update">Update4</a></p>
<p><span>that5</span> <a href="#" class="update">Update5</a></p>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.update').live('click', function() {
        $(this).siblings('span').replaceWith("Updated that!");
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcRbb/)

Comment: Interesting! It looks like something I have to take into account often. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create functions in a loop. With jQuery, there's no need for an explicit loop at all.

```
$(function()
{
    $('span[id^=sp]').each(function(n)
    {
        $('#update' + n).click(function(e)
        {
            $('#sp' + n).replaceWith(this);
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/4TVMa/

---

You can do *way* better than that, though:

```
$(function()
{
    $('p > a[id^=update]').live('click', function(e)
    {
        $(this).prev().replaceWith(this);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/xySGW/

Comment: Thanks for the codes. The first works well in the actual code I am using. But the second looks cleaner. I'll dive into that one further.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $("a[id^='update']").click(function(){
        var index = this.id.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
        $("span#sp" + index).replaceWith(this);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```