# jQuery function using the latest value instead of the value present at creation

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $body = $("body");
   for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       var $a = $("<a>");
       $body.append($a);
       $a.text(i);

       $a.click(function() {
           alert(i);
       });  
   }
});
```

Clicking on any of the anchors will alert the number `10`, when I'd of expected it to alert the value of `i` of when the function was created.

To get it working, I've just used `data` to append the ID to the anchor and I retrieve it within the function, but this just seems really messy. Why can I not specify the value when the function was created?

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/8JF45/1/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event doesn't get added in a for-loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332589/event-doesnt-get-added-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`jQuery.each()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method and keep your code a little cleaner.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $body = $("body");
   $.each(Array(10), function( i, v ) {
       $("<a>",{ text:i,
                 click:function() {
                    alert(i);
                 }
        })
         .appendTo( $body );
   });
});
```

Comment: Just a note: though this may look cleaner, allocating an Array to do a loop's job is huge overkill.  though it is trivial in the case of ten elements, take 1000 and you're allocating quite a bit of space just to do a single integer's job.

Comment: @Anthony: It just creates an Array with the `length` set at 1000. JavaScript Arrays are sparse. Remember it's just an Object with numeric indices and some fancy behavior.

Comment: Sure but this is the exact kind of thing that creates maintainability nightmares.  This would be the first line of code eliminated in a code review.

Comment: I don't see how it's any less maintainable than `for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)`

Comment: Now your manager wants it to do evens up until 368 (inclusive).  With a for loop this is simple changing bounds and increment.  With the array **trick** I have to think.  That's a maintainability problem.  *EDIT: Also: say they want it from 10 down to 1 instead, that is quite a bit messier with the trick than with for loop.*

Comment: Yes, if what was simple iteration up to a limit suddenly becomes something very different, you'd need to take a minute and change some code.

Comment: @Anthony: I don't know why you're trying to pick a fight. You aren't making much of a point. Obviously I'm referring to the simple iteration specific to that in this question and answer. You started off with a claim that an Array set at 1000 would require quite a bit of space. Then you stated that changes would be a maintainability "nightmare". Now you're diminishing the significance of those changes. At this point, you just seem to be looking for a fight. That's not what StackOverflow is about. I'll be happy to respond to constructive comments, but if you have none to offer, please stop.

Comment: Not trying to pick a fight. Just pointing out what I think is best. I still gave you a +1 for the nifty answer.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a closure, because the value of i changes until it is 10, and that function doesn't have a local copy of i, it uses the i in the scope of the outer function which has changed to 10:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $body = $("body");
   for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       var $a = $("<a>");
       $body.append($a);
       $a.text(i);

       $a.click((function(i){ return function() {
               alert(i);
           }
       })(i));  
   }
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8JF45/2/)

Comment: The event handler is already a closure. What you added is an *immediate* or *self-invoking* function. This function, though also a closure, does not make use of this characteristic (accessing variables from higher scopes).

Answer (score 3):

You need to do it in closure:

this should work:

```
   $a.click(function(index) { return function() {
       alert(index);
   };  }(i));
```

EDIT: or without the syntax madness:

```
$a.click({index: i}, function(e) { alert(e.data.index); });
```

Comment: +1 Definitely a much nicer syntax in the 2nd example, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `i` in your click function is not interpreted at "creation time". it's interpreted at runtime, when the click event has been fired. That means the click handler will be accessing the `i` as it stands after the loop has exited.

To get around it, you have to pass `i` in as a paramter:

```
$a.click(function(i) {
```

that'll embed the CURRENT value of `i` into the function at the moment the function is defined.

Comment: This does not work: `$a.click(function(i) { alert(i); });`  I'm pretty sure that just alerts `[object Event]` or `[object Object]` or something like that.  You might want to write out the closure.

Answer (score 0):

You could separate the listener for `$("a").click()`.

```
var $body = $("body");    
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){        
    var $a = $("<a>");        
    $body.append($a);        
    $a.text(i);            
}

$("a").click(function() {            
    alert($(this).text());        
});
```

Working example at: http://jsfiddle.net/z6r3Z/

Comment: That's wrong in so many ways, but thanks anyway. I want the value of i, not the text of the anchor.

Comment: Are you not setting the text of the anchor to the value of i?

Comment: Only in this example. Apologies for confusing you, but this doesn't help at all. See the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

With your example script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $body = $("body");
   for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       var $a = $("<a>");
       $body.append($a);
       $a.text(i);

       $a.click(function() {
           alert($(this).html);
       });  
   }
});
```