# jquery increment value

Tags: jquery, variables

I'm not educated in javascript so I nedd help. Got jquery code like this

```
$('.player-1').click(function(){
    $("#mediaplayer-1").show();
});

$('.player-2').click(function(){
    $("#mediaplayer-2").show();
});

$('.player-3').click(function(){
    $("#mediaplayer-3").show();
});
.....
```

So the question is how do write variable (mediaplayer-1, mediaplayer-2....) so you don't have to write the same lines all the time. I mean increment value of the number of this id

Comment: For a beginner in JavaScript your code is excellent to read. That is a big advantage. Why make it harder when it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need a correct triggering method:

```
$('.player-1, .player-2, .player-3').click(function () {
    // Do something
});
```

Or make it dynamic by adding `player-trigger` class next to `player-1` and etc:

```
$('.player-trigger').click(function () {
    // Do something
});
```

Now you need to cut the unique ID out from your "ID-class" (`player-1`). Also note, that Im removing the `player-trigger`..or this wouln't work:

```
$('.player-trigger').click(function () {
    var player_id = $(this).removeClass('player-trigger').attr('class').replace('player-', '');
    alert('Player is ' + player_id + ' in this case!');
});
```

And now lets put all this together with the `show()` function:

```
$('.player-trigger').click(function () {
    var player_id = $(this).removeClass('player-trigger').attr('class').replace('player-', '');
    $("#mediaplayer-" + player_id).show();
});
```

So in this case, your HTML should look kinda like this:

```
<span class="player-1 player-trigger">Show player</span>
<div id="mediaplayer-1">Das ist das eine player hier</div>

<span class="player-2 player-trigger">Show player</span>
<div id="mediaplayer-2">Das ist das eine player hier</div>

.. etc
```

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/hLfuH/1/**

---

However, as you probably noticed, it removes the `player-trigger` class, though it looks cool..you might want to do this like this:

```
<span id="player-1" class="player-trigger">Show player</span>
<div id="mediaplayer-1">Das ist das eine player 1 hier</div>
```

.. etc

```
$('.player-trigger').click(function () {
    var player_id = $(this).attr('id').replace('player-', '');
    $("#mediaplayer-" + player_id).show();
});
```

**Example 2: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/hLfuH/2/**

Comment: cool, thanks for this great explanation! thank you all guys I've learned a lot through your answers

Answer (score 2):

The right thing to do is to give the event listener to ONLY the parent of them all.

```
$('parent of your player elements').click(function(e) {

    // e.target is now the element which originated the click event

    // here you can check for the element class and
    // retrieve the corresponding element to show

});
```

Only one click event listener for all your elements at once, no matter how many.

This is how event listener should be implemented, this way you save a lot of resources.

Check this [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/q9bjv/).

I used a regex to parse the right class and find the ID of the player, then use the ID to find the element you want to show dinamically.

Comment: Edited with a concrete example. Anyway I suggest you to give them an ID instead of a class, like id="player-1" and so on, because ID are meant to identify different unique objects.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a for-loop:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    $('.player-' + i).click(function(){
        $("#mediaplayer-" + i).show();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 1; i < maxNum; i++){
    $('.player-' + i).click(function(){
        $("#mediaplayer-" + i).show();
    });
}
```

where maxNum is the total number of handlers you are trying to attach to

Answer (score 0):

You need to be wary of closures if you're using a for loop, see this question - [Event doesn't get added in a for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332589/event-doesnt-get-added-in-a-for-loop)

Try -

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    $('.player-' + i).click((function(i) {
        return function() {
            $("#mediaplayer-" + i).show();
        }
    })(i));
}
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/KQH8f/

Comment: These `for` methods have a drawback. You always need a max. number of the players. I think in the OP's case the players amount is dynamic. There for `for()` as a dynamic solution is not good.

Comment: @Kalle It's not difficult at all to find the max number of players, even if they come and go.. the OP code is ugly and impossible to mantain.

Comment: @Jose Yes of course, for example: [`$('div[class*=player-]').size();`](http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/KQH8f/1/). But IMO, `for()` loop is unnecessary.

Comment: @Kalle I agree for loop is completely unnecessary. Better to use one event listener for the parent only.